# posts can have same title - approach to have unique url is not working properly

Tags: php, laravel

I have the route below to show a specific post details page: "http://proj.test/{slug}" for example "http://proj.test/test-post" if the name of the post introduced was "test post".

The issue is that, can exist posts with the same name, so the url like "http://proj.test/test-post" will not work properly. Because can exist more posts with the same "test post" name.

So it should be necessary to besides the slug add in the url the id of the post.

So, I have a post controller to create a new post, so I was trying to insert in the slug column of the post the slug with the id of the post: (I dont know if this is a good approach to handle this issue)

```
$post = Post::create([
    'name' => $request->name,
    ...
    'slug' => str_slug($request->name."-".Post::id)
]);
```

But it appears "Undefined class constant 'id'". Do you know how to fix the issue?

show method of FrontController to show the post details view:

```
public function show($slug){
        $post = Post::where('slug', $slug)->first();
        return view('post.show')->with('post',$post);
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/{slug}', [
    'uses' => 'FrontController@show',
    'as'   =>'show'
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case where posts might not have unique slugs, you should follow the Stackoverflow approach - which is `/id/slug` where slug doesn't do anything except provide a friendly view.

The following is a link to this actual question - note how the slug doesn't in-fact matter. Sure it redirects onto your question with the right slug, but initially the slug doesn't do anything (the id does):

`stackoverflow.com/questions/49331496/this-can-actually-be-anything`

So your code might end up looking like:

```
public function show($id, $slug){
    $post = Post::find($id)->first();

    // if you want to redirect if the slug doesn't match, like SO
    if($post->slug !== $slug) {
       return redirect()->route('post.show', ['id' => $post->id, 'slug' => $post->slug]);
    }

    return view('post.show')->with('post', $post);
}

Route::get('/{id}/{slug?}', [
    'uses' => 'FrontController@show',
    'as'   =>'post.show'
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but its appearing "Missing required parameters for [Route: show] [URI: {id}/{slug?}]. " with that solution. Also I have to change from "redirect->route(..." to "redirect(..".

Comment: Updated - was missing () on redirect. And 'as' should be 'post.show' not 'show'

Comment: Thanks, but its appearing the error "Missing required parameters for [Route: posts.show] [URI: {id}/{slug?}]" on the view file.

Comment: The link to the post is "<a href="{{route('posts.show', ['slug' => $post->slug],['slug' => $post->id])}}".

Comment: The error is in the file "UrlGenerationException" on "public static function forMissingParameters($route)
    {
        return new static("Missing required parameters for [Route: {$route->getName()}] [URI: {$route->uri()}].");
    }".

Comment: You are passing 'slug' twice and calling posts (not post)? It should be `route('post.show', ['id' => $post->id, 'slug' => $post->slug])`

Comment: Note - the redirect should be post.show not show as well (updated answer)

Comment: Awesome, nice one!

Answer (score 0):

```
$post = Post::create([
    'name' => $request->name,
    ...
    'slug' => str_slug($request->name."-".Post::id)
]);
```

This doesn't work because a) there is no static method `id` on a model, b) you can't get an id of the model before actually saving it to the database.

The simple (and still more elegant) solution would be to check if a post with that slug already exists and only append a number to the post if it does. That way the majority (probably) of the posts will have a url without a number appended to them.

Something like this:

```
// Create a slug
$slug = str_slug($request->name);
if (Post::where('slug', $slug)->first() !== null) {
  $n = 0;
  do {
    // Increase n and append it to the slug
    $newName = $slug . '-' . ++$n;
    // Iterate until the slug is NOT found in the database,
    // which means it's unique 
  } while (Post::where('slug', $newName)->first() !== null);
}

$post = Post::create([
    'name' => $request->name,
    ...
    'slug' => isset($newName) ? $newName : $slug
]);
```

But probably a nicer way of doing it would be to prefix the slug with either user's name (still not necessarily unique) or timestamp or something else.

Answer (score -1):

Jon,

The 'Laravel' way to do this, or at least the most efficient way, would be to just use the Post's id in the route rather than the slug.  So if AJAX, just put the $post->id in a data field and pull it from javascript when submitting.

The route might be something like

```
Route::get("test/{post}", 'Testing\TestController@showTest');
```

Then on your controller, you could either pull the Post object by

```
$post = Post::find($post);
```

or use Route Model Binding and just typehint the controller function:

```
public function showTest(Post $post){ etc }
```

For your other question above about setting the id into the slug, this is probably not a good way to go...  However, if you need to, I would recommend a two step process $post = create(); then $post->slug = 'slug'.$post->id.  Again, not the best way to go, but it would work...

And of course you can always pass a slug through the route, but I would first look at the purpose for which you are looking to do this - is it purely cosmetic, or are you looking for a way to identify the post?  You can always add a loop into the controller to look up all the posts with that slug... but it is a lot easier to send the id, which you will always have access to, and then sort as above.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Im not using AJAX. But so with that solution is not possible to have the slug in the url? Is not possible to have with a slug and a id, for example like: "http://proj.test/test-post-2"?

Comment: AJAX doesn't matter - you can add the unique identifier on the form  when you open it (check 'form model binding').  To answer your question, yes, you CAN have a slug and an id, but it seems like extra work - as you said, the slug might be non-unique.  Why not just do it by the guaranteed unique id?   If you are trying to push the slug through POST just to see what it is, you can 1) pull in your model in the controller and check, or 2) send it along with the form (hidden or regular) so it shows up directly in the controller.

Comment: I wouldn't say that's the 'Laravel' way of doing it. There are legit use cases for having slug in an url.